# Want to retrieve data from database using servlets and display it in jsp

Tags: database, servlets

I want to retrieve data from database using servlet and show it into a jsp file ,but what is retrieved is only the first row of the table.I want to be retrieved all rows.Could anyone help me? Thanks,and here is my code:

Servlet:

```
    try{

        DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
        Connection con = connection.Connect();
        ResultSet rs;
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        java.sql.PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT Nume,Descriere,Ingrediente,Mod_preparare,Imagini,Total_grasimi,Total_carbohidrati,Total_proteine,Total_calorii FROM reteta");
        rs=ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            //name
            String Nume = rs.getString("Nume");
            request.setAttribute("Nume",Nume);

            //descripton
            String Descriere = rs.getString("Descriere");
            request.setAttribute("Descriere",Descriere);

            //images
            String Imagini = rs.getString("Imagini");
            request.setAttribute("Imagini",Imagini);


       request.getRequestDispatcher("/retete.jsp").forward(request, response);


        }

    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {
      e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally
    {
      out.close();
    }
}
```

Jsp:

```
        <a href="images/{Imagini} " class="gall_item"><img src="images/${Imagini}" alt=""></a>
        <div class="gall_bot">
        <div class="text1"><a href="#">${Nume} </a></div>
        ${Descriere} 
        <br>
        <button type = "submit" class = "btn" >more</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting attributes and forwarding the request within the while loop: that's probably why you are not getting the result you are expecting

You should use each field to create an object and each time around the loop store the newly created object in a collection (array, arraylist, linkedlist map...the choice is yours), then outside the loop create an attribute whose value is the collection populated with the object created in the while loop and finally forward the request to the Jsp

```
// create a new collection be it an array, arrayList, linkedList....
YourCollection yc = new YourCollection();

while(rs.next()){
        //name
        String Nume = rs.getString("Nume");
        //descripton
        String Descriere = rs.getString("Descriere");
        //images
        String Imagini = rs.getString("Imagini");

        // create object with db data;
        YourClass yourObject = new YourClass(Nume, Descriere, Imagini);
        // add object to collection
        YourCollection.add(yourObject);
}
// create attribute from collection
request.setAttribute("YourCollection", yc);

request.getRequestDispatcher("/retete.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Within the Jsp you will be able to easily access the attribute and loop through the collection with a foreach JSTL tag (for instance) and the instance variables of each object via expression language (I used the dot notation in the example)

```
<c:foreach var="yourVarName" items="${YourCollection}">

            <a href="images/{yourVarName.imagini} " class="gall_item"><img src="images/${yourVarName.imagini}" alt=""></a>
            <div class="gall_bot">
            <div class="text1"><a href="#">${yourVarName.nume} </a></div>
    ${yourVarName.descriere} 
            <br>
            <button type = "submit" class = "btn" >more</button>
             <!-- check closing divs.... -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</c:foreach>
```

Note: the properties accessed via dot notation correspond to the instance variables of each object and need not to be capitalized in compliance with the javabean specification.

Comment: Modified as you said:  Servlet --> ArrayList<String> datalist = new ArrayList<String>();
         
         while(rs.next()){
           
       datalist.add(rs.getString("Nume"));
        
       datalist.add(rs.getString("Descriere"));
       
       datalist.add(rs.getString("Imagini"));
       
        
         } 
         request.setAttribute("Ehealth", datalist);
       
     request.getRequestDispatcher("/retete.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: JSP-><c:forEach var="var" items="${Ehealth}">      <div class="grid_4">
        <div class="gall_block">
          <div class="maxheight">        
            <a href="images/{Imagini} " class="gall_item"><img src="images/${var.Imagini}" alt=""></a>
            <div class="gall_bot">
            <div class="text1"><a href="#">${var.Nume} </a></div>
            ${var.Descriere} 
            <button type = "submit" class = "btn" >more</button>
      </c:forEach> But I have this error:javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'Nume' not found on type java.lang.String

Comment: Did u get any error?

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'Nume' not found on type java.lang.String

Comment: You have not created an object. Properties belong to objects

Comment: Define a Java class with instance variables Nume, Descriere and Imagini and a constructor that takes those 3 fields as parameters, then use each String retrieved by the database to create an object of the same class you have defined. Then populate the arraylist with those objects...

Comment: Created a class where are get and set methods implemented for my db data.( Ehealth health = new Ehealth();)Added to my list (datalist.add(health);) and now I have this error : javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'Imagini' not found on type beans.Ehealth

Comment: It has to be something like Ehealth health = new Ehealth(nume,descriere,imagini);

Comment: You need a constructor that takes those 3 parameters and don't capital letters for the instance variables

Comment: Can I send you an archive with my code and take a look?I'm beginner in programming and is hard to me to understand.

Comment: I have some network issues, can't connect via PC at the moment I'm texting through my phone...you might want to send me a txt file with your code in it

Comment: Sent,Thank you very much!

Comment: I got it. Give me some time to go through it and I'll email you back

Comment: Don't worry about that,take your time,Thank you!